# How to use a different Git version in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, git-for-windows

Git in Visual Studio is very slow for me. One of the things I try to fix this problem is to use the installed Git for Windows. [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) shows Visual Studio keeps using the included Git version.
My PATH variable contains

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;
```

but not

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin\git.exe
```

In Visual Studio *External Web Tools* options I pointed the previous two Git paths to their Git on Windows equivalent.

[image: Visual Studio options External Web Tools]

I'm using the following versions:

- Visual Studio Professional 2017 version 15.6.4 (latest updates applied)
- Git for Windows Git-2.16.2-32-bit.exe (latest version)
- Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit

Comment: Visual Studio will use the version that's packaged with it as it's a very slimmed down version which exactly matches the behaviour that Visual Studio expects as it parses the output generated by Git. It's interesting that Git is slow. Can you share a bit more about your git repository, your virus scanner, possible corporate policies that could be in place on your laptop, the location of your Git repo (network drive, local disk, local SSD)? Are there specific actions which are slow? Is it better with the latest preview version?

Comment: VS approach here sounds a lot like [Embrace, extend, and extinguish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish)...but they don't do that anymore....right...in no way would they prefer everyone to use Team Services.

Comment: Once I just removed the bundled git subdirectory, then it started use the system's one :) But I don't think it would help with the performance.

Comment: There's no embrace, extend, extinguish going on here.  This decision was focused primarily on predictable command output and behavior.  MinGit is an official Git for Windows subset.

Comment: @Liam, not sure what you're aiming at. The folks working on Git for Windows are working for Microsoft and they have contributed back a lot of security and perf fixes to git in order to support much larger repository sizes. At the same time creating a very slimmed down version of Git that's easy to distribute and supports the important git commands is a huge boon for tools like the VSTS Agent and other tools that want to ship a reliable and predictable version of git. It's been Embrace, Extend and Extend more and improve performance and security and extend it some more. No extinguish whatsoever

Comment: @ofthelit, with which Git operations were you experiencing performance issues?

Comment: Viewing the history of a branch or file, displaying the changes on files, switching branches, fetch, pull, push, rebase,... everything really.
It appears to work fine for some other colleagues. I moved my `.gitconfig` and VS settings off the network drive. Symantec Endpoint Protection used for security. The repo is on my local laptop SSD but has a lot of unneeded packages checked-in.

Comment: The 60 seconds slowdown mentioned at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/79527/team-explorer-slow-git.html is very familiar, but that is already fixed. Trying a preview version might not be a bad idea. I'll make a new question when my hunches are exhausted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of a full Git for Windows install, [VS includes a MinGit install](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/09/03/whats-new-in-git-for-windows-2-10/).  MinGit is an official subset of the Git for Windows distribution and is available for download alongside the Git for Windows installers.

VS does this for several reasons.  One reason to bundle MinGit is for reliable and predictable behavior.  VS needs to parse the output of various Git commands, and not all commands have porcelain output available.  That output changes from time to time, and the parsers have to be updated.  By including MinGit, VS can verify the behavior of the commands it uses before each release.  As an example, this happened with the 2.16 release of MinGit, which brought output changes in a handful of commands that we'll need to handle before moving to that version.  Deleting the MinGit copy included with VS may break the Git integration.

A secondary reason is to cut down on the Git for Windows install size since it is several hundred megabytes.  MinGit is under 50 megabytes.